# ¿Cómo Seleccionar una fila de un dbGrid mediante una posición?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Estoy intentando seleccionar por código la fila de un `DbGrid` dada una posición, he intentado con esto pero no lo hace, ¿alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

```
 HelpGrid.SelectedIndex := ListPosRows[I];
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar con mayor detalle qué es lo que quieres lograr? Esto porque el DBGrid es un _visor_ de los datos del `DataSet`, que potencialmente puede tener muchos registros, quizás no todos en memoria. Si quieres _ubicar_ la rejilla en un registro, basta con que hagas ese registro el registro actual del `DataSet` subyacente.

Comment: lo que quiero es que cuando guarde cambios en la tabla no perder la seleccion de las filas, actualmente la pierdo cuando guardo en la tabla, pense que con la lista de posiciones de las filas seleccionadas, podia seleccionarla por codigo una vez que se actualice el grid

Comment: Ok, creo que convendría entonces que expongas todo el caso en tu pregunta, para que se pueda escribir una respuesta a ese problema que tienes. Para no perder detalle, te invito a leer antes [ask]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente un **DBGrid** no es más que una ventana que te permite ver una parte de los registros de una tabla. Por lo tanto cuando hablamos de registros de un **DBGrid** realmente deberíamos estar pensando en los registros de una tabla (o mejor dicho de un **Dataset**).

Para seleccinar una fila de un **DBGrid**, creo que debes pensar en selecionar un registro de un **Dataset**.

Asegúrate de que el **DBGrid** tiene las opciones de `dgRowSelect` y `dgMultiselect` a `True` y puedes probar un código como este para seleccionar diferentes filas del DbGrid.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
  DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
end;
```

Ver el resultado a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, tengo los dbgrid con las propiedades gRowSelect y dgMultiselect a True, pero lo que pasa aca es que cuando actualizo en dbgrid pierdo las filas que tenia seleccionada, y pense que teniendo las posiciones de la seleccion de las filas, despues que actualizaba podia seleccionar esas posiciones para no perderlas

Comment: @RaidelFonseca En ese caso debes utilizar bookmarks. Antes de actualizar genera bookmarks para los registros selecionados y después de Refrescar los restauras.